# What documents do I have to include with my i-130 spouse and daughter petition, If I file from overseas?

Tags: usa, immigration

Good day.

I'm filing an i-130 for my spouse and daughter, I have completed the form however I'm not really sure what supporting documents do I have to file? Can they be copies of the originals? The documents are in Spanish, do they have to be translated by a certified official or they can be translated by anyone?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything should be a copy. If you send originals you will not get it back. Yes, you need to translate them if they are in a foreign language; anyone can translate it as long as they certify that they are fluent in English and the other language, and that the translation is an accurate translation of the original document (copies of both the original and translation attached). The necessary documents are described in the I-130 instructions, but here is a summary for your case:

I-130 for your spouse:

- check for $535
- proof of your US citizenship (you said in an earlier question that you were born in the US, in which case: a US birth certificate or a valid US passport)
- Form I-130A
- two photographs of you and two photographs of your spouse (not sure about the photographs of your spouse as the instructions seem to imply that that is only necessary if they are in the US)
- your marriage certificate
- if either of you were previously married, evidence of termination of those marriages
- various evidence of bona fide marriage, including evidence of comingling of finances and assets like joint bank accounts, joint leases, insurance that cover both of you, putting each other as the beneficiary on various accounts; also birth certificates of children you had together; you can also show pictures of you guys together, etc.

I-130 for your daughter:

- check for $535
- proof of your US citizenship (again, since you were born in the US: a US birth certificate or a valid US passport)
- your daughter's birth certificate (since you are the mother)

P.S. Make sure you are using the 02/27/17 edition of the I-130 form (edition date is at the bottom of each page), because previous editions are not accepted.

Comment: Thank you for your help. We have bought three cars but they are all on my name with my husband lastname. The register information for those cars are in spanish, do those have to be translated also?

Comment: @COPITO: If it only has your name, then I am not sure whether it is helpful.